# C - Function to allocate dynamically a 3 dimension array (using malloc)

Tags: arrays, function, pointers, 3d, malloc

I created this function to allocate dynamically a 3D array.

```
int ***create_3D_Array(int nb_block, int nb_lin, int nb_col) {
    int i, j;
    int ***A = (int***)malloc(nb_block * sizeof(int**));
    for (i = 0; i <nb_col; i++) {
        A[i] = (int**)malloc(nb_col * sizeof(int*));
        for (j = 0; j < nb_lin; j++) {
            A[i][j] = (int*)malloc(nb_lin * sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

I then used it here

```
int ***all_blocks = NULL;
all_blocks = create_3D_Array(54, 5, 5);
```

However, it is not working correctly because when I want to give a value to my 6th block `all_blocks[5]`, the program stops working.

Is there any error in my function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions are incorrect in your allocation loops. The outer loop should run to `nb_block`, the second malloc should allocate `nb_lin * sizeof(int*)` and the third malloc should allocate `nb_col * sizeof(int)`.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
int ***create_3D_Array(int nb_block, int nb_lin, int nb_col) {
    int i, j;
    int ***A = (int***)malloc(nb_block * sizeof(int**));
    for (i = 0; i < nb_block; i++) {
        A[i] = (int**)malloc(nb_lin * sizeof(int*));
        for (j = 0; j < nb_lin; j++) {
            A[i][j] = (int*)malloc(nb_col * sizeof(int));
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

Note that it might be simpler to use a direct 3D array:

```c
int (*all_blocks)[5][5] = malloc(54 * sizeof(*all_blocks));
```